# Could I disbale decode request body in spring handling HTTP POST with header application/x-www-form-urlencoded (or get the original request body)

Tags: java, spring, http, x-www-form-urlencoded

Working in a special situation, I must hanldle a request with ConentType:application/x-www-form-urlencoded but not encoded when delivering.
Spring may decoded the request body so I will get a wrong body for eg:
correct string:"a+b+c"
spring decoede ones:"a b c"

I couldn't change the behavior of the guy who posting the method, so I think I need a way to do so as title said:
disbale decode request body in spring handling HTTP POST with header application/x-www-form-urlencoded (or get the original request body)

Can someone help me this, plz...

Answer (score 0):

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html
I changed the params:parseBodyMethods, and now any post http methods won't be parsed anymore.